# Cannot add scipy to pycharm

Tags: python, scipy, pycharm

This line:
from scipy.stats import norm
(The first in file, and even if it is the only line)

results in these errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/user/Documents/KalTech/DataAnalysis/Code/DataScience/Correlations.py",
>   line 3, in        from scipy.stats import norm
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\scipy\stats__init__.py",
>   line 345, in     from .stats import *
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py",
>   line 169, in     import scipy.special as special
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\scipy\special__init__.py",
>   line 640, in     from ._ufuncs import *
>
> File "_ufuncs.pyx", line 1, in init scipy.special._ufuncs
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your current numpy version and installing the numpy-MKL library which is available [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy).

Download the right version for your python version and pip install it.